# Optimize query with large number of data on mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a more than 10 million data from my table and needs to pull it in order to display in the report. The origin of data was extracted from csv and all of them are in text format. and here is how it looks  from my table:

[image]

I tried to query with limit on 1000 only and it will display quickly however If I am going to have a date filter for e.g getting 1 day data and it will take around 25-30 secs:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, '_', 1), '%m/%d/%Y') FROM myTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(time, '_', 1), '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN DATE('2019-9-3') AND DATE('2019-9-3');
```

I already tried to create an index on time column which I am using for filter but still got the same result:

[image]

Is there any suggestion/comments how can I improve the speed to pull the data. TIA

Comment: Maybe your hardware could be the problem? How much does RAM and processing power does it have? I hope you are not running this on single core processor as that is bound to take a long time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply functions to a column as part of your search, it can't use an index, even if you define an index for that column.

You should also use a proper `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type for the column, which will require dates be stored in YYYY-MM-DD format, not a string column in MM/DD/YYYY format.

If you store the dates properly, you can do this:

```
SELECT DATE(time) FROM myTable
WHERE time >= '2019-09-03' AND time < '2019-09-04';
```

That will make use of the index.

Answer (score 3):

You are storing your dates/timestamps as text, which is going to force you to doing suboptimal things like calling `STR_TO_DATE` all over the place.  I suggest adding a new bona fide `datetime` column, and then indexing that column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN time_dt DATETIME;
```

Then, populate it using `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET time_dt = STR_TO_DATE(time, '%m/%d/%Y_%H:%i:%s.%f');
```

Then, add an index on `time_dt`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON myTable (time_dt);
```

And finally, rewrite your query so that the `WHERE` clause is sargable (i.e. so that it may use the above index):

```
SELECT DATE(time_dt)
FROM myTable
WHERE time_dt >= '2019-09-03' AND time_dt < '2019-09-04';
```

Side note: You need to use `%H` in the format mask with `STR_TO_DATE`, because your hours are in 24-hour clock mode.

Comment: GREAT answer.  Nice complete solution.  Only thing left is to clean up the unnecessary column.